# How to find the nearest object using script?

Tags: python, scripting

I have *object A* and another 4 objects (*B, C, D, E*). I need to find the nearest object to *A*, How to script this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your objects' origins are at the center of their geometry and that object sizes did not matter (since you did not mention it), you can use the following python script to get the nearest object to *object A*. Don't forget to change `'Cube-A'` in the script to whatever name you're using for your *object A*

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube-A'] #change Cube-A to your object A name

closet_obj = None
distance = -1

def get_distance(p1, p2) :
    [x1, y1, z1] = p1
    [x2, y2, z2] = p2
    return (((x2-x1)**2) + ((y2-y1)**2) + ((z2-z1)**2)) ** (1/2)

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj == o or not o.type == 'MESH':
        continue
    d = get_distance(obj.location, o.location)
    if distance < 0 or d < distance:
        distance = d
        closet_obj = o

if not closet_obj is None:
    print("object", closet_obj.name, "is closest to", obj.name, "with distance of", distance)
else:
    print("no mesh objects found!")
```

Or if you need to be more precise taking origins and size into consideration, you can iterate through all the vertices in all the objects by using this python script:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube-A'] #change Cube-A to your object A name
obj_vertices = obj.data.vertices

closet_obj = None
distance = -1

def get_distance(p1, p2) :
    [x1, y1, z1] = p1
    [x2, y2, z2] = p2
    return (((x2-x1)**2) + ((y2-y1)**2) + ((z2-z1)**2)) ** (1/2)

def get_vertex_global(o, v):
    return o.matrix_world @ v


for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj == o or not o.type == 'MESH':
        continue
    mesh = o.data
    for v1 in mesh.vertices:
        for v2 in obj_vertices:
            d = get_distance(get_vertex_global(o, v1.co), get_vertex_global(obj, v2.co))
            if distance < 0 or d < distance:
                distance = d
                closet_obj = o

if not closet_obj is None:
    print("object", closet_obj.name, "is closest to", obj.name, "with distance of", distance)
else:
    print("no mesh objects found!")
```

Comment: What if one object is simply a few times bigger or has an origin point in a weird place? It's origin point or location might be further away, but it may be the closest...

Comment: yes i was thinking of this possibility but the OP did not mention it. I did get the impression that he probably assumed the origin was in the center and just needed a rough estimate disregarding the size of the object.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys i also provided the script if size and origins mattered

Comment: I think it's a good answer,  I upvoted it, but regarding the problem it may be more complicated than it seems. What if the object is a long cylinder with vertices at the ends and its middle part is closest, but vertices are further away than other objects?..

Comment: thanks! i think in this case it needs to be defined what "nearer" meant like from what reference points and conditions and whatnot XD

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact in my demand origin is the geometry center (I didn't consider so much).